# Proving two field extensions aren't equal for different cube roots

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory, extension-field

Let $ d_1, d_2$ be square-free integers $\neq 0, \pm 1$, with $ d_1 \neq \pm d_2 $.
We can assume that $ x^3 - d_i $ and $ x^3 - d_i^2 $ are irreducible over $ \mathbb{Q}$.
I've shown that
$
\text{Tr}_{\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{d_i})/\mathbb{Q}}(\sqrt[3]{d_i}) = \text{Tr}_{\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{d_i})/\mathbb{Q}}(\sqrt[3]{d_i^2}) = 0 \text{ for } i = 1,2$.
I now want to show
$
\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{d_1}) \neq \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{d_2}).$ How do I do this?

Comment: Have you tried proving by contradiction yet?

Comment: yes I have, by assuming that $d_1^{3} $can be written as a Q-linear combination of basis elements from Q(cube root d_2). But I havent got any further .

Comment: Let $\sqrt[3]{d_1} = a +b \sqrt[3]{d_2}+c\sqrt[3]{d_2^2}$, then taking the trace will give you $a=0$. Try proceed from that.

Comment: if the bases are ordered differently, wouldn’t i get different traces?

Comment: If your definition of trace is based on the matrix representation of linear map, then no, since similar matrix have the same trace.